# I need to enter parameters for classes, where should I do it? Also why is cout considered bad practice to use in classes?

Tags: c++, class

I've got class Human and class MealPlanner.

I create Human object in class Mealplanner, but I need parameters to be entered into Human. It has age, weight and height for example.

So first it's like

```
MealPlanner::MealPlanner(){
    humanP = new Human;
    /// But human actually has parameters like Human(weight, age, ...) 
    /// I just need those parameters to be entered by the user

}
```

Should I just make a function inside MealPlanner like

```
MealPlanner::enterInfo(){
    int age;
    cout << "enter age" << endl;
    cin >> age;
    /// and so on
    ///and then do 
    humanP->setAge(age);
}
```

Normally I'd enter all the info inside main() and then pass the object to MealPlanner, but I have a task to basically make the object inside MealPlanner class and the best way to do is to make Human object inside there. But human needs info and where should I let the user enter this info?

Also why is cout bad practice to use inside classes?

Comment: The user doesn't always want to write to the terminal. However for toy projects it's fine

Comment: So if I'm making a project and the User wants something to be calculated based on his age etc. why wouldn't he want to enter something..?

Comment: Cout is for writing, you mean cin. Also it's entirely possible the user provides input over xml, or even as packets over a socket. Again, the basic streams are fine for projects like yours

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `humanP` is a pointer to type `Human` that is a member variable (i.e. a field) of `MealPlanner`. Since it is a pointer, you need to invoke `operator new()` to initialize it - but in this particular case (as you create in owner's constructor) it may be better to make `humanP` a regular variable.

That way it will get default constructed implicitly - you don't need to construct it explicitly.

Regarding reading input/output: ideally you should split user input/validation and data modification. So, think of a layer class or function performing the in/out procedure, then invoking `MealPlanner::setHumanData(age, weight, height)`.

Comment: So basically I leave everything as it is, just make another method called setHumanData, ask the user to enter info and set that info to the Human class fields using setters?

Comment: You could do that, although you mix up responsibilities. Try to split it - think of layers. Consider this: if you picture `MealPlanner` - what does it represent? Is console processing something related to `MealPlanner`? Ideally, you'd keep your data abstract of the input method, i.e. whether the data came from console, or file, or UI, or whatever is hidden from the actual data class, `MealPlanner` in this case.